# Open local file on IOS

Tags: ios, ms-word

I downloaded some files from server and stored into local file system ,and i tried to open with  MS word Application

```
ms-word:ofv|u|file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D34248E4-61FF-4C80-9B9F-18D4B7EB866D/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540folter%252Ffolter/news.docx
```

but i get message from office word saying :

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKe4C.jpg)

Path locale file system:

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D34248E4-61FF-4C80-9B9F-18D4B7EB866D/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540folter%252Ffolter/news.docx

Any help please ?

Comment: How did you download the file?  Using which app?  One app can't open files from another app's sandbox.

Comment: @Paulw11 i'm downloading file with expo's methods and tried to open file with Linking.openURL

Comment: That won't work because the file will be in your apps sandbox. Other apps can't access that. You can use a UIActivityViewController to let the user "share" the file to Word or you could `UIDocumentPickerView` to let them export it to the files app or you can Mabel [`UIFileSharingEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW20) so that users can browse to your app's document folder and open the file from Word.

Comment: @Paulw11 do you know where i should save file to be able read by MS word app ?

Comment: Where you are already saving it should work as long as you set UIFileSharingEnabled and allow open in place

Comment: @Paulw11 i'm developing app with react native not with iOS

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you are using. You are running on iOS and need to operate within the constraints of that platform. Even when you use react native, it emits an Xcode project that gets compiled to produce the iOS app bundle. That is why you still need a Mac. There will be an info.plist file somewhere.

Comment: @Paulw11 I enabled `UIFileSharingEnabled`. Now the file is shown in **Files** App, but still can't open. Got the same error.

Comment: Enabling file sharing still won't let another application open from your sandbox. I really don't think you can do what you want to do. By exposing your apps files to the system, the user should be able to open the file from within the word app but you can't send the file to the word app